# Measure $\mu$ is 0.

Tags: complex-analysis, measure-theory, complex-numbers, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

I am reading the paper of Balazard ,Saias and Yor. Let, $$f(z)=(s-1)\zeta(s) $$ where $s=\frac{1}{1-z}$ and $\zeta(s)$ denotes the Riemann zeta function. Denote by $$\exp\left[\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{e^{i\theta}+z}{e^{i\theta}-z}d\mu(\theta)\right]$$ the singular interior factor of $f.$
Denote by $$f^*(e^{i\theta})=\lim_{r\to 1^-}f(re^{i\theta})$$
Then by Generalised Jensen's formula $$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \log|f^*(e^{i\theta})|d\theta=\log|f(0)|+\sum_{|\alpha|<1,f(\alpha)=0}\log\frac{1}{|\alpha|}+\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}d\mu(\theta)$$

> The measure $\mu$ associated to the singular interior factor of $f$ is 0. For this it suffices to reuse the argument developed by Bercovici and Foias for the interior factor of the functions $(\theta-\theta^s)\zeta(s)\frac{(s+\frac{1}{2})}{s}$

**Question** How does the measure $\mu$ associated to the singular interior factor of $f$ is $0$?.

Comment: Please answer. I will happily give it a check mark.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Your question is a good one, but a complicated one. Oftentimes it takes a day or two or three for a tricky question to be answered, and this one has only been up for an hour! There's no need to spam the comments with requests for an answer.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor Thank you for your kind advice. I will keep this in mind.

Comment: Is there another answer by using the method used by Bercovici and Foias??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This result involves a bunch of theorems in Hardy Space theory which can be found in the classic references by [Duren](https://www.elsevier.com/books/theory-of-h-superscript-p-spaces/duren/978-0-12-225150-4) or [Garnett](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/0-387-49763-3) (chapter II especially)

I will quote the relevant theorems and then explain how they imply the result:

1. If $f \in H^p(\mathbb D), p>0$, then $f$ has non-tangential finite limit on the unit circle ae $d\theta$; if we call that $f^*(e^{i\theta})$, one has $\log |f^*| \in L^1(d\theta), |f^*| \in L^p(d\theta)$
2. There is a (unique up to constants of modulus one) decomposition $f=BSF$ where $F$ is outer (non-zero and determined by $\log |F^*|=\log |f^*|$), with $|F^*|=|f^*|$ ae, $B$ is a Blaschke product with the zeroes of $f$ inside the unit disc and $S$ is a singular inner function which is determined by a positive singular measure (wr $d\theta$) $\mu$; both $|B^*|=|S^*|=1$ a.e. $d\theta, |B(z)|, |S(z)| <1, |z|<1$ (unless either is trivial so identically $1$)
3. If $f$ is analytically continuable across some arc $I$ of the unit circle, then $B,S,F$ are so too (and of course vice versa) which concretely means that $B$ has no zeroes accumulating there and the measure $\mu$ has support disjoint from $I$
4. If the singular factor is non-trivial (ie measure $\mu \ne 0$, so $S$ is not $1$), then there is a point $e^{i\theta}$ for which $f(z) \to 0, z \to e^{i\theta}$ non-tangentially; this is very easy to see when $\mu$ is a point mass at some $e^{i\theta}$ so $S(z)=e^{-c\frac{e^{i\theta}+z}{e^{i\theta}-z}}, c>0$ hence $S$ decays exponentially at $e^{i\theta}$ while $F$ cannot increase too much since $F^*$ is in some $L^p$

Now for $f(z)=(s-1)\zeta(s), s=\frac{1}{1-z}$, one easily shows that it is in $H^p$ for all $p<1/2$ so it has a decomposition $f=BSF$ as above; we know that $(s-1)\zeta$ is analytically continuable across the finite part of $\Re s =1/2$ which corresponds with $f$ being so across $|z|=1, z \ne 1$; by Theorem 3 above, it follows that the singular measure $\mu$ which determines $S$ is concentrated at $1$ or trivial. If we were in the first case we would get $\lim_{r \to 1, r<1}f(r)=0$ (Theorem 4 above)

But now $x=\frac{1}{1-r}>0, x\to \infty, r \to 1$ and  $f(r)=(x-1)\zeta(x)$ by defintion; but this would mean $\lim_{x \to \infty, x>0}(x-1)\zeta(x)=0$ and that is of course not true as the limit is infinity; hence $S=1$ and the measure $\mu$ is zero. Incidentally $B=1$ is equivalent of course with RH so $f$ is outer iff RH is true

Comment: edited to make it that clear

Comment: Thanks a lot. Why does $\lim_{r \to 1, r<1}f(r)=0$?

Comment: theorem 4 in the post - edited again to make that clear; the singular factor decays exponentially then, while the modulus cannot increase too fast - see references for rigorous proof)

Comment: $\lim_{x \to \infty, x>0}(x-1)\zeta(x)=0$ and that is not true as the limit is infinity; hence $S=1$. How is $S=1$?

Comment: the measure $\mu$ is either concentrated at $1$ and then $S(z)=e^{-c\frac{1+z}{1-z}}, c>0$ or the measure $\mu$ is trivial (identically zero) so $S=1$; we want to prove the latter as per Balazard et others and we show that the former (measure non-zero concentrated at $1$) leads to a contradiction that a limit is, on one hand, zero from Hardy Space theory and on the other hand infinity from zeta function theory

Comment: Thanks. Why are we taking $lim_{ r \to 1, r<1} f(r)$. Why are we taking $r \to 1$? $f(z) $ has a singularity at $z=1$. So are we taking $r=|z| $ or $r=z$?

Comment: Because we so choose to get the required contradiction; by general theory we are allowed to take non tangential limits and radial limits are the simplest such, so they definitely qualify

Comment: I am asking that why are we taking limit as $r \to 1, r<1$ of $f(r)$? What is $r$ here?

Comment: not sure of the question $z=r, 0 \le r<1$ is in the unit disc so we can take the limit $r\to 1$ of $f(r)$; in general of course it may or may not exist for an arbitrary function defined in the unit disc; here we know that if the singular measure is nontrivial, this limit must be zero

Comment: So here $z=r$ or $|z|=r$?

Comment: $z=r$ as we take a radial limit; more generally we could take a non tangential limit but that is unnecessary here

Comment: So if $f(z)=\frac{z}{i-z}\zeta(\frac{1}{i-z})$ then $r=i$?

Comment: I mean $f(z)=\frac{z}{i-z}\zeta(\frac{1}{i-z})$ has a singularity at $z=i$ , so $r=i$?

Comment: Please reply. This is my last doubt.

Comment: If $r =i \in \mathbb{C}$ then we cannot write $r<1$ in the limit. As complex numbers don't have ordering.

Comment: your use $ir$ that tends radially to $i$

Comment: Are you saying that $\lim_{r\to 1, r<1} f(ir)$?

Comment: Are you saying that $\lim_{r \to 1, r<1} f(ir)$? I will give your answer a check mark after this doubt.

Comment: do you mean $\lim_{r\to 1, r<1}f(ir)$?

Comment: wait - $1/(i-z)$ doesn't send the unit circle into the critical line but into the line $\Im s =-1/2$ so one would need $f(z)=\frac{z}{i-z}\zeta(\frac{i}{i-z})$ to see stuff about the critical line

Comment: So the limit is $\lim_{r\to 1, r<1} f(ir)$? If we had this hypothetical function.

Comment: yes - nothing changes - this is a rotation of the other function

Comment: $f(z)=(s-1)\zeta(s)$ where $s=\frac{1}{1-z}$ so $f(z)$ has a singularity at $z=1$. So in the limit $\lim_{r\to 1, r<1}f(r)$ why we are taking only $r\to 1$.

Comment: because we CHOOSE that; we have a goal - prove that $\mu =0$ and a method - show that if $\mu \ne 0$ we get a limit zero on one hand and same limit non-zero on the other hand; choosing $r \to 1$ gives us the second part, Hardy space theory gives us first part

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can't we prove $\mu=0$ by using the method used by Bercovici and Foias?

Comment: this is their method adapted to this situation - they discuss a different function which is related to $\zeta$ but which appears in a different more general criterion about critical strip zeroes (Beurling criterion about $L^p$ density of some function space corresponding with no zeroes in $\Re s >1/p$ ); a few deeper Hardy space results like Beurling invariant space theorem is needed there

Comment: Thank you so much. I am giving your answer a check mark. Can you please give a reference for $\mu=0$?

Comment: Which book should I refer for Theorem 4? Duren? Or Garnett?

Comment: not sure about your question for a reference - Balazard et others paper will do as they use the result; the proof above is based on the Bercovici Foias reference but I made it explicit to include the theorems one uses as the article of Foias and Bercovici is written for professional mathematicians so all this stuff is well known and actually it is fairly trivial stuff for the paper's level which has some difficult non-trivial stuff; Balazard et others paper is on the other hand fairly elementary but highly unlikely to lead anywhere as RH goes beacuse of that

Comment: Please give me a reference for Theorem 4.

Comment: I gave you a proof sketch but look in  Garnett chapter II

Comment: So in Garnett Chapter 2 Theorem 4 is given? Can you please tell me the page number. Please.

Comment: Is it theorem 6.2 page 73?

Comment: it follows from Theorem 6.2 page 73 (which implies applying l'Hopital enough times that $S(r)/(1-r)^n \to 0, r \to 1$ (in the case here of $\mu$ concentrated at $1$ but non-trivial) while $|(1-r)^3F(r)|$ is bounded since $F \in H^{1/3}$ (actually one can easily show that $|(1-r)^3F(r)| \to 0$)

Comment: In , $S(r)/(1-r)^n$ why are we dividing by $(1-r)^n$?

Comment: $f(r)=S(r)F(r)B(r), |B(r)| \le 1$ so $f(r)=((1-r)^3F(r))\frac{S(r)}{(1-r)^3}B(r)$ and now all terms are bounded, while the middle one goes to zero, so the limit is zero - note that $F(r)$ is unbounded (actually $O(1/(1-r)^2)$ by general zeta theory) but $S(r)$ would decrease very fast, faster than any $(1-r)^n$ if it were nontrivial

Comment: Thank you so much. I am indebted to you for your kind gesture and help. Which book should I follow if I want to study Hardy spaces having no background of it?

Comment: Duren is the standard (and easiest reference) and I always keep it handy; Garnett is good but more advanced; since the subject is so vast, it also depends on what you want to get; Chapters 1-3 in Duren are excellent for a quick intro

Comment: Thanks again. It's very helpful. I will follow it religiously

Comment: You have answered many questions on MSE but you have not asled a single question. Why?